# For- in loop dynamic closed range

Tags: for-loop, swift

What is the correct way of having a dynamic close range of `for-in` loop? I got an error on this part `for z in 1...[10-x]{`

```
for x in 1...10{

    for y in 1...x{
        print(" ")
    }

    for z in 1...[10-x]{
        print("*")
    }

    println()

}
```

Error:

`Playground execution failed: <EXPR>:26:15: error: 'ClosedInterval<T>' does not have a member named 'Generator'
    for z in 1...[10-x]{`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[10-x]` denotes an *array* (with the single element `10-x`). You'll want "normal"
parentheses:

```
for z in 1 ... (10 - x) { ... }
```

or just

```
for z in 1 ... 10 - x { ... }
```

because `...` has a lower precedences than `-`.

As you noticed, this does not work for `x = 10` because ranges with `end < start` are not allowed in Swift.

To execute a loop `n` times you better use the range `0 ..< n` with the range operator that omits the upper value. This works for `n = 0` as well:

```
for x in 1 ... 10 {
    for y in 0 ..< x {
        print(" ")
    }
    for z in 0 ..< 10 - x {
        print("*")
    }
    println()
}
```

Comment: I tried that as well, it does not work. I got this error: `fatal error: Can't form Range with end < start`

Comment: Sorry I think it does work but I still have that fatal error :)

Comment: I got it now, the fatal error happens when (10-x) becomes zero :)